# CakePHP 3.1 plugin join tables not using custom datasource

Tags: plugins, datasource, cakephp-3.0

For some reason, when I use containable with a join table in a plugin, Cake uses the default datasource instead of the custom one.
I've been all over stackoverflow and Google, and tried everything I could find to no avail.

I'm trying to create a plugin that uses its own datasource:

plugins/Vorien/NPCData/config/app.php:

```
return [
    'Datasources' => [
        'npcdata' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'npcdata',
            'password' => '********',
            'database' => 'npcdata',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'flags' => [],
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'log' => false,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => true,
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
        ],
    ],
];
```

plugins/Vorien/NPCData/config/bootstrap.php:

```
try {
    Configure::config('npcdata', new PhpConfig(Plugin::path('Vorien/NPCData') . 'config/'));
    Configure::load('app', 'npcdata');
    ConnectionManager::config(Configure::consume('Datasources'));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage() . "\n");
}
```

I used bake to create everything with the parameters:

```
  -p Vorien/NPCData -c npcdata
```

My join tables look like:

```
$this->belongsTo('Personas', [
    'foreignKey' => 'persona_id',
    'className' => 'Vorien/NPCData.Personas'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Archetypes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'archetype_id',
    'className' => 'Vorien/NPCData.Archetypes'
]);
```

And have:

```
public static function defaultConnectionName()
{
    return 'npcdata';
}
```

Running a hasOne or hasMany:

```
$persona = $this->Personas->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['People']
]);
```

When I try to run anything with a HABTM:

```
$persona = $this->Personas->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Archetypes']
]);
```

I get:
    Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
with the Auto-Tables error for PersonasArchetypes

I dug around a lot until I realized that the key was 'my_app'@'localhost' which meant that even with the defaultConnectionName set in PersonasArchetypesTable Cake was using the 'default' connection only for join tables.  When I set the default connection in config/app.php everything works.  Of course that won't work for a plugin.

Note: The join table isn't alphabetical but that was changed to optional in 3.0.  I did try renaming the join tables anyway.

Has anyone else run into this?  Could it be a bug?  Or am I just missing something?

EDIT:  I've also tried adding the database name before the table in all three Table files of the HABTM.  (database.table instead of just table)

Comment: Did you set the **bootstrap** option to true while configuring your plugin in config/bootstrap.php? [Like this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-configuration) : 
`Plugin::load('npcdata', ['bootstrap' => true]);`

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug when using the table name for the joinTables parameter in a plugin where it wasn't setting the connection from the table object.

Using the plugin prefixed table object in either the joinTables or the through options worked fine.

There's a patch [#9018](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/9018)  with plans for a more robust fix in 3.2.12.

Many thanks to the Cake folks for all their help.  And patience.